# Is Moshiach going to be a person or an era?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, messiah

Does Judiasm require one to believe that there will be an actual person who will be the Messiah or is belief in a Messianic period  (brought about by God) enough for one to believe in?

Answer (score 1):

See [Who is Moshiach Ben Joseph and what does/did he do?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13359/who-is-moshiach-ben-joseph-and-what-does-did-he-do) for a discussion for what Mashiach the person may accomplish during his lifetime.

The gemara Succah (52b) discusses a person known as 'Mashiach ben Yosef' who is destined to die during Gog U'Magog. Moreover, the Rambam Melachim (11:1) describes how the King Mashiach will develop a monarchy. It's a stretch to understand Mashiach referring to anything but an individual person based on these sources.