# Will there be two Mashiachs?

Tags: messiah, messianism

I've always thought that *the* Mashiach is one. But I recently heard from a friend that there is *Mashiach ben David* and *Mashiach Ben Yoseph*. And that one will bring the jews from the diaspora and the other will reconstruct the Temple or something like that. I don't know the sources of this and I've never heard anything like this, but is this true in some way?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/49030/does-the-idea-of-moshiach-ben-yosef-negate-the-anti-missionary-argument-against

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to our tradition, the term "Mashiach" describes the anointed monarch. So, we are waiting for the monarchy to be restored, with everything related - full independence and religion freedom(e.g. freedom from idolatry).
In our sources it is said that IF we merit to get the glorious ruler - we'll get Mashiach ben David, but if we not - we will get Mashiach ben Yosef - e.g. the hidden one, like in Egypt.
But any way if it will be Moshiach ben Yosef, afterwards will be Moshiach ben David for sure - as it is predicted by our prophets.
So, we are waiting for the monarchy, but it could be established not necessarily  straight ahead.