# How can the Rebbe be considered Moshiach?

Tags: rambam, messiah, chabad

I've talked to various Chabad Rabbis, and I can say for certain that at least 1 definitely believes that the Rebbe could be Moshiach.

In trying to prove this, he cites Rambam's Mishneh Torah ([Melachim Umilchamos, chapter 11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e511n.htm#8), halachah 4):

> **ד:** וְאִם יַעֲמֹד מֶלֶךְ מִבֵּית דָּוִד הוֹגֶה בַּתּוֹרָה וְעוֹסֵק בְּמִצְוֹת כְּדָוִד אָבִיו. כְּפִי תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב וְשֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה. וְיָכֹף כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל לֵילֵךְ בָּהּ וּלְחַזֵּק בִּדְקָהּ. וְיִלָּחֵם מִלְחֲמוֹת ה'. הֲרֵי זֶה בְּחֶזְקַת שֶׁהוּא מָשִׁיחַ. אִם עָשָׂה וְהִצְלִיחַ וּבָנָה מִקְדָּשׁ בִּמְקוֹמוֹ וְקִבֵּץ נִדְחֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל הֲרֵי זֶה מָשִׁיחַ בְּוַדַּאי. וִיתַקֵּן אֶת הָעוֹלָם כֻּלּוֹ לַעֲבֹד אֶת ה' בְּיַחַד שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר כִּי אָז אֶהְפֹּךְ אֶל עַמִּים שָׂפָה בְרוּרָה לִקְרֹא כֻלָּם בְּשֵׁם ה' וּלְעָבְדוֹ שְׁכֶם אֶחָד: ‏

"If a king will arise from the House of David who diligently contemplates the Torah and observes its mitzvot as prescribed by the Written Law and the Oral Law as David, his ancestor, will compel all of Israel to walk in (the way of the Torah) and rectify the breaches in its observance, and fight the wars of God, we may, with assurance, consider him Mashiach.

If he succeeds in the above, builds the Temple in its place, and gathers the dispersed of Israel, he is definitely the Mashiach."

The Rabbi I spoke with asserts that the Rebbe definitely fit into the first category mentioned by the Rambam, the "assumed Mashiach", as he was very well versed in the entire Torah, and encouraged many to properly observe Judaism. In this point I find no discrepancy with what the Rabbi is saying. It's this next point which I'm having trouble with.

This Rabbi also goes on to say that the Rebbe fits into the category of the definite Mashiach, as outlined by the Rambam. "He builds the Temple in its place" -- this refers to 770 ("in its place" need not refer to Jerusalem, but rather to "the Mashiach"'s place, explains the Rabbi). "He gathers the dispersed of Israel" -- this refers to when the Rebbe exported a large number of Jews from the Soviet Union into the land of Israel. The Rabbi explained this all to me.

Why I'm having with this is the Rambam's [next clause](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e511.htm):

> **ט:**  ואם לא הצליח עד כה, או נהרג--בידוע שאינו זה שהבטיחה עליו תורה, והרי הוא ככל מלכי בית דויד השלמים הכשרים שמתו.  ולא העמידו הקדוש ברוך הוא אלא לנסות בו רבים, שנאמר "ווּמִן הַמַּשְׂכִּילִים יִכָּשְׁלוּ לִצְרוֹף בָּהֶם וּלְבָרֵר וְלַלְבֵּן עַד עֵת קֵץ כִּי עוֹד לַמּוֹעֵד" (ראה [דניאל יא](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00794.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2),לה).‏

"If he did not succeed to this degree or was killed, he surely is not the redeemer promised by the Torah. Rather, he should be considered as all the other proper and complete kings of the Davidic dynasty who died."

The Rebbe is no longer alive. This appears to contradict what the Rambam stated just above. However, the Rabbi explains to me that Rambam only specifies "...or was killed," whereas the Rebbe died of natural means (actually, he never directly said that the Rebbe died). Furthermore, Rambam then says he is to "...be considered as all the other proper and complete kings... WHO DIED". To be, this seems to clearly imply that the Rambam isn't simply referring to the Mashiach as someone who wasn't killed, but to someone who hasn't yet died.

All this is one way to look at the Rambam's words, but to me it seems very clear that the Rambam is referring to someone who actually builds the third Beis Hamikdash in Jerusalem, gathers the people of Israel from all over the Earth, and to someone who is actually alive!

How can this belief that the Rebbe is / has the potential to be Mashiach at all be properly justified, considering the clear words of the Rambam? (No offense intended, I just want to know).

EDIT

All of your answers are great, but the best is the one I heard from my real-life Rabbi, "Let moshiach come and we'll find out!"

Comment: I can't find "the Rambam's next clause" in the Rambam I have online. Is it missing something?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Yes, it was. I found a more complete link.

Comment: Interestingly I was just reading Gershom Scholems book Sabbetai Sevi and when describing the response of the believers upon hearing of the death of their Messiah was to quote almost all of the same proofs that lubavitchers do to prove that he was not really dead/transposed/coming back/etc. Very scary

Comment: @Mefaresh from making of a gadol I was also present when the venerable author, R' Bezalel Landau, held a discussion about this matter with my father during the latter's 5742 (1982) visit to Israel and related that a distinguished rash yeshiva in Jerusalem had accused him of "falsifying the image of the 
Gaon" by omitting the issue of the Gaon's hithnagduth. R' Landau 
pleaded with my father, "How can I publicize the Gaon's prohibi-
tion on intermarriage with hasidim and possibly cause families to 
break Up?"

Comment: Cont. My father agreed that the five chapters he had pre-
pared be left unpublished but not be destroyed, saying, "Have 
them prepared for publication but desist from [publishing them] 
until such time as may come when events will necessitate their 
publication." He explained in veiled terms, "They must be ready in case a certain someone should do an ugly thing'.

Comment: Cont. He was referring to messianic fantasies simmering in a hasidic circle in Israel, the adherents of that group had fomented a political feud along hasidic-mithnagdic lines - and my father felt that the eventual publication of these chapters would help the general hasidic public shake off the messianics should their fantasy get out of hand. As it turned out, my father's concerns were well founded: a large segment of that hasidic cult did declare its leader to be the Messiah.

Comment: Yeah I've see this before. Very scary. Look at the  history of the Frankists. History repeats itself

Comment: There are several inconsistencies in the messianic reading. He interprets מִקְדָּשׁ as broadly as possible, yet interprets שמתו as narrowly as possible. He interprets כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל as... actually he pretends the word כל doesn't exist!

Comment: @Ephraim I think (not absolutely certain) they they rationalize the fact that the mission isn't complete yet by asserting that the Rebbe is still alive in some way (either through the shluchim,or somehow literally)! In 770i was told by another Chabad Rabbi that 5 minutes before shacharis everyone waits for the Rebbe to walk in the door, and after 5 minutes they say, "well I guess the rebbe won't be joining us today"

Comment: I want to note that this site seeks to present Judaism's views. The vast majority of Judaism rejects his messianic status. Thus one would expect / hope that his messianic status would not be generally consistent with traditional sources. The fact that a minority claim his messianic status is indicative that there are arguments to made, although weak, to support it. It is therefore somewhat difficult for readers to then answer the question. The majority of readers hold that indeed readings used to support his messianism are misreadings.

Comment: Even the first section - to be considered a possible mashiach - needs to be interpreted absolutely illogically and against the clear meaning of the Rambam to apply to the Lubavitcher Rebbe. And if it is "interpreted" in this way, it could just as easily be misinterpreted to be any one of hundreds of Torah giants over the ages.

Comment: @user2016831 Since you choose as your final quote to quote & translate a portion from MT, 11:4, you should address the entire quotation. Rambam states explicitly in his Intro to MT that his language is precise, like the language of Nasi in the Mishnah. 1) What is the difference between הרג and מות? 2) What is meant by the different spelling of בית דויד as contrasted with the previous spelling of בית דוד? Also 3) In the phrase "אלא לנסות בו רבים", who are the רבים", the majority, or some other 'Rabim", like the ערב רב? Which is consistent with the majority Torah view?

Comment: 4) When it says, "עַד עֵת קֵץ כִּי עוֹד לַמּוֹעֵד", what Keitz is it referring to that is mentioned from Daniel 11:35? What exactly takes place then? For what it's worth, the Rebbe specifically used the phrase "עוד חזון למועד" in discussing the 1st Gulf War and those things that had not yet been fulfilled, but would be. Your doubts appear to come more from not understanding the meaning of the words used by Rambam and the sources that he is referencing. Those I have listed here would be a good place to start.

Comment: See Yaron Rueven's video on this on YouTube

Comment: Ephraim כל in Halacha many times refers to the majority additionally in various Sichos the Rebbe asserts that all Yisroel did Teshuva and brings proofs that even a thought of Teshuva is enough.

Comment: Moshiach may be from the dead. https://shmoishelmoshiach.com/download/

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy No he may not. He may have been from the dead had that generation merited it, but alas they didn't.

Comment: Wow. This is an insane thread, incredibly discouraging. Shaul Behr's answer is the only correct one: This is the way human beings sometimes twist their thinking to get the results they want. I note that gedolim sometimes give very difficult answers to questions (see the mefarshim on the law of Yashan), but they are aware that the answers are difficult, and say so and explain why they think it's true anyhow. This isn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the subject, the Rebbe did not teach the idea that he would be considered to have fulfilled the halachic status of "Moshiach with certainty" (מָשִׁיחַ בְּוַדַּאי) even up to this day. According to the Rebbe's teachings, this cannot occur until *after the resurrection of **the seven Shepherds** and **the eight Annointed Individuals***.

The idea that he met the criteria to be considered "presumed to be Moshiach"  as outlined by Rambam in the Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Melachim, chapter 11 is in keeping with the Rebbe's teaching.

This concept of the halachic status of *Presumed to be Moshiach* as it applies to the Rebbe is built upon the halacha sefer, *Yechi HaMelech* which carries the approbation of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein among many others, like for example Maran Ovadia Yosef.

[image: Haskama of Ovadia Yosef to Sefer Yechi HaMelech 21 Cheshvan 5752]

This didn’t even begin to gain ground until 1984. The Rebbe first acknowledged the book’s existence in 1992 as printed in his approbation to the 2nd edition. It is also worth noting that the Rebbe discouraged pushing this view in places that were not receptive to it.

The Rebbe did not teach that halacha (Jewish law, like is found in the Mishnah Torah of Rambam) was to be understood in any way other than according to its plain meaning. And with that said, the second half of Halacha 4 in Hilchot Melachim, chapter 11, meaning building the Mikdash in its place (on the Temple Mount in Jerusalem) has not be fulfilled yet.

For those Lubavitchers who mistakenly claim that the halacha you cite in your question:

> וּבָנָה מִקְדָּשׁ בִּמְקוֹמוֹ

means 770 Eastern Parkway in Brooklyn, New York because it is possible to read "בִּמְקוֹמוֹ" as *in his place (the place where Moshiach happens to be located at any given time)*, they are in disagreement with the principle of following the plain meaning as taught by the Rebbe concerning this halacha. (For details of this see Kuntress Davar Malchut: Chiddushim u'Biurim b'Hilchot Melachim, Chapters 11-12, published 2 Iyar, 5751)

The word “מקדש” is masculine and in the context of the sentence (meaning requirements that pertain to acquiring the status of *Moshiach with certainty*), “מקומו” means it’s place (the place of the Mikdash) in Jerusalem, not his place (meaning wherever Moshiach is found).

It is worth noting that the Rebbe does differentiate and state that following the plain meaning of Rambam regarding acquiring the halachic status of *Presumed to be Moshiach*, those laws can pertain to ***his*** place, meaning his geographic location. He mentions this specifically in the context of fighting G-d's wars in order to acquire the status of *Presumed to be Moshiach*.

Regarding the status of *Moshiach with certainty* the text states, “Moshiach *will build* the Mikdash in its place” and after that gather in the exiles, etc.

The plain meaning is that Moshiach will, after he is *presumed to be Moshiach* according to halacha build the third Temple in its place, and only after that will the Jewish exiles outside of Israel be gathered into Israel and Jerusalem.

But historically, the Jews of the Soviet Union were leaving under Prime Minister Gorbachev in the early to mid 1980s. The placing of the foundation stone (Even HaPinah) by the Rebbe was in late August of 1988 (which is not in keeping with the Rebbe's explicit teaching that Moshiach's participation in the actual construction would be the final act which completes the construction, not the first). And the lifting of all emigration restrictions was in 1989.

In fact, the Soviet Union collapsed in 1991 long after the Jewish emigration from there was in full swing .

And everything associated with the Gulf War and how 770 Eastern Parkway was equated with the Mikdash, like is mentioned and cited explicitly by the Rebbe quoting the Yalkut Shimoni on Isaiah took place in 1991 and 1992.

This means that the chronological order is wrong for the status of *Moshiach with certainty* according to the plain meaning. What happened historically is not the clear fulfillment of the halachic requirements for anyone, including the Rebbe, to be Moshiach with certainty.

So how is all this to be understood according to the teachings of the Rebbe, who appears to be *presumed to be Moshiach* ?

The Rebbe did teach, like all the Rebbe's before him, that everything which exists in the physical, has its precursor and source in the spiritual.

This is nothing unique to Lubavitch. It is a consistent principle in Torah throughout the ages.

In the Torah of Moshe Rabbeinu to parshat Bereshit and the commentaries there, this is the reason behind the basic repetition in Bereshit about the story of creation, the first time with G-d’s name, *Elokim* and the second time with *HaShem Elokim*. The beginning is the spiritual precursor and the second is the literal, physical expression according to the plain meaning.

In the case of the building of the Temple in its place, meaning on the Temple Mount in Jerusalem by Moshiach, the spiritual precursor to its literal, plain fulfillment was the laying of the cornerstone to 770 by the Rebbe himself. There is an interesting and relevant discourse connected to this idea found in Sefer Karnayim by Rabbi Aharon of Kardina and the commentary Dan Yadin of Rabbi Shimshon of Ostropolia, Discourse 14 and also in Sefer Kehillat Yaacov by Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles, ערך מצפ״ץ.

The source for this concept was explained in the Rebbe's kuntress entitled, "Mikdash Mi'at Zeh Beit Rabbeinu she'ba'Bavel" from 20 Marcheshvan in the year 5752. But it is not the plain fulfillment of the law mentioned above.

In a similar fashion, the ingathering of the exiles mentioned in halacha has a spiritual precursor.

This is why the ingathering of the exiles appears ***before*** the return of the (nascent) Sanhedrin, the rebuilding of Jerusalem including the third Temple, and the full reestablishment of the monarchy of David through the "sprouting" of Tzemach David in the Amida prayer (meaning the Shemonah Esreh).

The order that appears in the Amidah is not identical to the order in halacha as found by Rambam in the Mishnah Torah. And those differences are discussed extensively in Kabbalistic writings and in Chassidic teachings, in particular within Chabad Chassidut.

This spiritual ingathering is supposed to be the ingathering and final tikkun, or "elevation of the Sparks of Holiness" from all of the mitzvot done by everyone from the beginning of creation until the completion of the process called "birrur HaNetzutzot".

This process is also described in other places as the reason for going into exile. The Jewish people went into this *exile* in order to gather these *sparks*.

But this principle and this language is nothing new. It is the same language and teaching we have in regard to the first exile of Egypt and the first redemption with Moshe Rabbeinu. When the Jewish people left Egypt, it was empty like the bottom of the ocean. The *sparks* had been collected and taken out from there.

This is also the teaching of the Alter Rebbe as found in [letter 130 of volume 1 of Igrot Kodesh of Rabbi Shalom Dov Ber, the 5th Rebbe](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31622&st=&pgnum=360). The Alter Rebbe is explaining there the view of the Ari z"l as found in Eitz Chayim.

But this is also not unique. It is also the teaching referred to by Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato as found in [section 2 of Derech HaShem, Hashgacha HaIshit (Divine Supervision of Human Beings), section 8](https://www.sefaria.org/Derech_Hashem%2C_Part_Two%2C_On_Personal_Providence.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) which says:

> ואולם **סידר האדון ב״ה שהשלימים וחשובים יוכלו לתקן בעד אחרים** וכמ״ש ותפגע בהם מדה״ד תחת פגעה בכלל העולם ואמנם **כיון שהם בעצמם שלימים וראוים לטוב** שהם מתיסרין רק בעבור האחרים ודאי שתתפיס מדה״ד במועט בהם כמרובה בחוטאים עצמם ולא עוד אלא **שעי״ז זכותם נוסף וכחם מתחזק וכ״ש יכולים לתקן את אשר עיותו האחרים והיינו כי לא די שיתקנו למה שבבני דורם אלא גם לענין כל מה שנתקלקל העולם מאז נהיו בו חטאים ועד עתה ובודאי שאלה יהיו אח״כ בקיבוץ השלימים ראשי הראשונים והיותר קרובים אליו ית״ש**.

The mechanism for this final elevation *of the sparks of Holiness* is accomplished by the Moshiach dieing and his soul ascending. These sparks ascend through their attachment to the soul of Moshiach.

The Rebbe discussed this concept in many contexts over many years.

One of them was in his Chassidic discourse entitled, ["Zeh Yitnu mi'Chatzit HaShekel" in the year 5748, parshat Mishpatim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15970&st=&pgnum=348). There he said that the leader of this generation, the last generation of exile and the first of redemption, would descend to death in order to remove death from the world.

But the most significant idea from this teaching was that the Rebbe associated this spiritual concept as a prerequisite for the literal, plain fulfillment of the mitzvah to rebuild the 3rd Temple.

This is in keeping with the principle taught by Rabbi Moshe Cordovero as found in Biurei HaMekubbalim b'Niglah on Tehillim 90:17, which quotes [Sefer Gerushin 91 at the end](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45021&st=&pgnum=52).

There it states that the 3rd Temple is required to be perfect not only in regard to itself, meaning in regard to its physical structure, but also in regard to those who build it. If those who build it are not perfect both spiritually and physically, the 3rd Temple would not be perfect.

The Rebbe says that to resolve the two (seemingly conflicting) views between Rashi and Rambam as to whether the 3rd Temple is built by G-d (meaning the third Temple descends from Heaven built by the *hands of G-d*) or by Moshiach (meaning that Moshiach will build the third Temple in a material, physical way, according to nature and in keeping with the plain sense of the halachic requirement), Moshiach will hang the doors to the third Temple, which according to halacha is considered completing the action of its construction which was started by G-d.

But as he points out, this still leaves the problem that by Moshiach doing the actual building while not in a state of spiritual and physical perfection, removes the *perfect and eternal* aspects from the third Temple like when it is built directly by G-d. The Temple is the product of the one who makes it.

The physical body of those who build the 3rd Temple (if they have a body) must be perfect. And as the Rebbe explains at great length in the Chassidic discourse, ["L'havin Inyan Techiyat HaMetim" found in Sefer HaMa'amarim Meluket, vol. 3, pg. 321](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15918&st=&pgnum=255), this condition is only possible when G-d resurrects the human being. Such a resurrected human being then becomes *The sprout of My field, the work of My hands for praise. [(See Isaiah 60:21)](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.60.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)*, like Adam HaRishon before the sin.

But this idea that Moshiach, after he has attained the halachic status of *Presumed to be Moshiach*, must be resurrected is really no surprise because as the Rebbe points out from [Sukkah 52b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.52b.10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) quoting Zechariah 2:3 which says:

> ויראני ה' ארבעה חרשים מאן **נינהו ארבעה חרשים** אמר רב חנא בר ביזנא אמר רבי שמעון חסידא **משיח בן דוד ומשיח בן יוסף ואליהו וכהן צדק**

and Micah 5:4 which says:

> והיה זה שלום אשור כי יבא בארצנו וכי ידרוך בארמנותינו **והקמנו עליו שבעה רועים ושמנה נסיכי אדם** מאן **נינהו שבעה רועים דוד באמצע אדם שת ומתושלח מימינו אברהם יעקב ומשה בשמאלו ומאן נינהו שמנה נסיכי אדם ישי ושאול ושמואל עמוס וצפניה צדקיה ומשיח ואליהו**:

and [Yoma 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.5a.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and numerous other sources, we know that at the very least, the 7 Shepherds and 8 annointed individuals are to be resurrected at the beginning of the days of Moshiach because they are needed in order to build the 3rd Temple. Among those named as being *amongst the first 15 to be resurrected* are **Eliyahu the prophet**, Moshe Rabbeinu and **Moshiach ben David**.

And in that context, it is no surprise that the Rebbe said explicitly in the Chassidic discourse, ["Gadol Yiyeh Kevod HaBayit" from the year 5722 as found on page 343 in Sefer HaMa'amarim Miluket, volume 4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25071&st=&pgnum=137), that, "this is among the reasons that the first activity of Moshiach after he will be 'presumed to be Moshiach' (a halachic status that must be understood according to its plain meaning) is building the Beit HaMikdash. Because this is the root of all the concepts that follow afterward."

And this follows the precise wording and order in the halacha brought by Rambam concerning acquiring the status of *Moshiach with certainty* according to its plain meaning.

Regarding your question about what difference it makes between being murdered or simply dieing as it relates to the halacha, it is the distinction made by the Rambam.

As explained in the non-censored versions of the Mishnah Torah, this law excludes Jesus from consideration as the Messiah because he refrained from fighting G-d's wars in his place and was also killed. That is to distinguish him from Bar Kochba, who did fight G-d's wars in his place but was unsuccessful ultimately in his wars and was killed in battle.

The concern of some over Rambam's pasak was because tradition taught that there was the possibility that Moshiach ben Yosef would be murdered.

But as we know from the Vilna Gaon, as recorded in Kol HaTor, Chapter 1:6:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngYd2.jpg), pg.24 in the 1994 Edition, due to all the prayers over the ages, that decree was overturned. And so, that detail of the halacha stands.

In this context it is worth pointing out that the Rebbe wrote in a letter in 5704, as recorded in a kuntress called *Torato Shel Moshiach* related to this idea, that the view of Rambam as found in Mishnah Torah appears to be that Moshiach ben Yosef and Moshiach ben David are one and the same individual.

And this seems to be one of the messages from the Haftorah to parshat VaYigash found in [Yechezkel 37:15-17](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.37.15-17?lang=he), which says:

> וַיְהִ֥י דְבַר־יְהוָ֖ה אֵלַ֥י לֵאמֹֽר׃
> טז וְאַתָּ֣ה בֶן־אָדָ֗ם **קַח־לְךָ֙ עֵ֣ץ אֶחָ֔ד וּכְתֹ֤ב עָלָיו֙ לִֽיהוּדָ֔ה** וְלִבְנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל חברו [חֲבֵרָ֑יו] **וּלְקַח֙ עֵ֣ץ אֶחָ֔ד וּכְת֣וֹב עָלָ֗יו לְיוֹסֵף֙** עֵ֣ץ אֶפְרַ֔יִם וְכָל־בֵּ֥ית יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל חברו [חֲבֵרָֽיו׃]
> יז **וְקָרַ֨ב אֹתָ֜ם אֶחָ֧ד אֶל־אֶחָ֛ד לְךָ֖ לְעֵ֣ץ אֶחָ֑ד** וְהָי֥וּ לַאֲחָדִ֖ים בְּיָדֶֽךָ׃

And even with that aside, it is worth noting that, in fact, there was an attempt to assassinate the Rebbe on the bridge crossing from Manhattan into Prospect Park, Brooklyn by [Rashid Baz in 1994](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_Brooklyn_Bridge_shooting), the actual year of the Rebbe’s passing. This corresponds to the nullified decree that Moshiach ben Yosef would be murdered.

Comment: "it is the distinction made by the Rambam" This is false.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to about it being Rambam's distinction only and being "false". Please see Daniel 11:14, 34-35 and comments from Malbim, Radak and others. And if you are implying in Halacha, there are not a lot of sources to point to for other views. Although Aruch HaShulchan HaAtid, in spite of quoting Rambam almost verbatim, drops this detail entirely.

Comment: I'm just saying Rambam makes no such distinction. The position of all of traditional judaism, rambam included, is that someone's death is proof they are not mashiach. (I have no idea what your pointing to in Daniyel or in Malbim there. I don't have Radak's commentary available but I feel quite confident it will be similarly unenlightening.)

Comment: In regard to the question of what you list as halacha 9 of chapter 11, it is actually the censored text of the Halacha 4 brought above it. The comment, "if he is not successful to this extent or is murdered", is referring to Moshiach with certainty which begins with same wording.

Comment: Regarding the idea that Moshiach cannot come from the dead in its plain sense is a denial of explicit statements in both Talmud, which I cited above, and the Prophets. It also ignores many classical commentaries regarding the opening lines of the Chumash, namely Bereshit 1:2.

Comment: And concerning the subject of kingship, all male descendants from the house of David are considered eligible to that inheritance. The question about whether the Rebbe fought G-d's wars in a literal sense is public record. There are numerous interviews which can be watched with past Israeli commanders and Generals who plainly acknowledge having received support and advice, including strategy and tactics from the Rebbe in every conflict that Israel was engaged in. And that is not to ignore the spiritual support even before conflicts broke out, like the tefillin campaign and other activities.

Comment: @YaacovDeane It can't contradict the Talmud as it is the position of traditional Judaism, or which the Talmud is a prime contributor.

Comment: At least in the case of Harav Ovadya Yosef, the author of Yechi Hamelech printed something that was not an approbation. See here: http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=99186

Comment: @N.T. If you read the actual reply to your question from Rav Avraham Yosef, he does not answer directly your question in the link pertaining to the specific books written by Rav Volpo. He says, his father didn’t give approbations to books. That means all books. And yet Rav Ovadia Yosef has what most would call approbations in many places. I have the original edition of Yechi MaMelech which deals only with understanding the language of Rambam in Mishneh Torah. The complete approbation from Rav Ovadia is reproduced there along with many other approbations from prominent Rabbeim.

Comment: Read it again: לא נותן הסכמות לספריו של הרב וולפא He clearly says Rav Volpo's sefarim did not receive haskamos.

Comment: @N.T. Makes you wonder what he means when he says his father “didn’t give haskamot” because his father gave haskamot to multiple books by Rabbi Volpo both before Yechi HaMelech and for Yechi HaMelech specifically. They were hand written in Rabbi Ovadia Yosef’s handwriting and on his stationary and dated. Perhaps Rav Avraham Yosef was unaware of his father’s activities. If you consider he was busy with his own activities with the military Rabbanut and kashrut supervision for Badatz Beit Yosef, perhaps he was unaware. Many other prominent Rabbis also gave haskamot to these books.

Comment: I can't say because I haven't seen the actual haskamos. If you post pics I could look at them. He admits his father gave a haskamah to a different sefer that was  then used for Yechi Hamelech.

Comment: @N.T. I have no interest in pursuing this any further. I know that these haskamot were given legitimately at the time. Like I said before, many other significant Gedolei Yisroel also gave haskamot to the same books including Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, Rav Moshe Stern and others. That 30 or 40 years after the fact some child or grandchild wants to attempt to rewrite history is pointless. I lived through this period and saw how the storylines evolved over time and all the politics from all directions including the politics of Rav Avraham Yosef. The politics is not true. It is Erev Rav.

Comment: Ok, but you won't convince many people if it is your word against his son. If you know the history, prior to his death, did anyone believe it was possible for the Rebbe to be Mashiach after he passed away?

Comment: @N.T. Anyone with common sense and who has raised children knows that declarations by a child that they know the specific actions of their parent (like they are gatekeepers to their parents actions) is simply a falsehood. This is very similar to when the Eida Chareidit and numerous other Gedolei Yisroel gave haskamot to Phil Berg (Shraga Feivish Grunberger) on the publication by the Kabbalah Research Center of his kabbalistic siddur with the kavanot of the Ari z”l. The denials after the fact are coming from the politics, not the truth.

Comment: Anything a child says is a falsehood? So much for mesorah. Just post pics of the  haskamah and we can see for ourselves. It is very easy to verify.

Comment: @N.T. Although not really relevant to this answer, per your request, I have added a screenshot of Maran Ovadia Yosef’s handwritten haskama to Sefer Yechi HaMelech which was given on 21 Mar-Cheshvan 5752. It is specifically titled “Haskama” & names the book by title. It also gives brief background to Rabbi Volpo and other books by him that Maran Yosef gave haskamot to in previous years. I have several of them.

Comment: Ok. It clearly is for that sefer. However, he says he only saw some pages of the sefer before it was completed. So that does not mean he agrees to everything in the sefer. This is why reading haskamos closely is so important.

Comment: @YaacovDeane was yechi hamelch sefer published before 3 Tammuz? If so you can't compare that to after

Answer (score 37):

I'm going to answer this question indirectly. I have had discussions with several Lubavitchers who have come up with some compelling (to them) reasoning how the Rebbe זצ"ל *can* be Moshiach, which leads inexorably to the conclusion that he *must* be Moshiach. I'm not going to attempt to express the arguments here, even though you have asked for them, because I personally am unconvinced by them (to say the least) and will therefore not be able to make a good case to answer your question directly.

But I will make the point that when the Rebbe was on his death bed, there was not a *single* Lubavitcher (that I know of) who brought any of these rationales to explain that even if the Rebbe would die, he would still be the Moshiach. As one *meshichist* said to me at the time, "Just as it is clear to me that the sun will rise tomorrow, so it is clear to me that the Rebbe will not die - and you will see he is Moshiach!"

In other words, all these arguments "proving" that Moshiach could be someone who has already died were all formulated only *after* they became necessary. They are all post-rationalizations. To my mind, this in itself makes the arguments specious; it has all the markings of a massive case of [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance), where the pain involved in admitting that they were wrong was so great that the *meshichistim* had to come up with some kind of explanation that allowed them to hang on to their previously held beliefs. To be clear: cognitive dissonance is not a mental disorder; it's something that affects *every single human being on the planet*. So it shouldn't be surprising that normal, healthy people should react in this way to an occurrence that seems to challenge a deeply held belief.

To summarize my answer: you asked, "How can this belief... be properly justified" - and my answer is: **There is no limit to the acrobatics that the intellect can perform when driven by cognitive dissonance.**

Comment: @ShaulBehr That no one at the time the Rebbe was”laying on his death bed” was discussing if he died is no proof at all. The appropriate, traditional Jewish response when someone is seriously ill is to pray fervently to G-d, who is the “Healer of everything”, to heal that person completely & to trust completely that G-d will hear, accept and answer that prayer without delay and in a way of open & revealed good both physically & spiritually.

Comment: @YaacovDeane "That no one at the time the Rebbe was”laying on his death bed” was discussing if he died is no proof at all." That was not his proof. His proof was that every single chasid would have insisted at that point that the meshiach will certainly not be someone who died. They would have insisted - the same as every other Torah Jew - that such a view is contrary to Judaism. And they would have believed it.

Comment: @MichoelR For those Chassidim of the Rebbe who were familiar with the Rebbe’s letter from 5704, prior to his receiving the yoke of the Nasiyut from his father-in-law, explaining the meaning of Rambam’s Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings, 11:4, they knew that the Rebbe stated the correct understanding of that section is that Moshiach ben Yosef and Moshiach ben David at the conclusion of the period called the Heels of Moshiach will in fact be the same individual. The Rebbe held that according to Rambam, all that is mentioned in connection with ben Yosef, including death,will be fulfilled by ben David.

Comment: My full impression of the time was that every chasid I knew, completely expected the Rebbe to get better. "The Rebbe is gezunt!" That is also my impression of every chasid I've ever talked to since: They had no such expectation at the time, and they were flipping out at the funeral. This whole line of thought was constructed afterwards, once their expectations were dashed. Pardon, but I don't think you're being honest with yourself.

Comment: @DoubleAA and others - the author of Kuntres Shmoi Shel Moshiach approached me offline and sent me a copy of the book. I haven't read it, but I did read the haskoma from Rav Zev Leff שליט״א, which made my eyes pop. Tachlis, Rav Leff recants his original position and concedes that there is a valid opinion in Judaism that Moshiach could be from the dead. That's intellectual honesty for you. Anyway, it may be worthwhile to pop over to https://shmoishelmoshiach.com/download and take a look.

Answer (score 20):

See Gil Students tremendous treatment entitled "[Can The Rebbe Be Moshiach?](http://moshiachtalk.tripod.com/)"

In [Chapter Five](http://moshiachtalk.tripod.com/moshiach_chap5.pdf) called What Counter-proofs can be
Brought? Rabbi Student brings the arguments that many meshichist lubavitchers use to argue that the Lubavitcher rebbe was/is/will be Moshiach.
From the beginning of the chapter:

> There are two types of proofs that are brought for the claim  that a
> dead person can be Moshiach. The first type is  passages from primary
> sources and the second is  commentary on these sources. The former
> tries to  demonstrate that Chazal considered it possible, or maybe
> even likely, that a resurrected figure can serve as Moshiach.  The
> latter attempts to show that regardless of what we think  the primary
> source actually says, there were commentators  who may have thought
> differently. This distinction is  important because it highlights that
> the value in a  commentary’s statement rests totally on the weight of
> who  the commentator is and not on what text the author is
> explaining. For example, if a relatively unknown twentieth  century
> rabbi wrote a commentary on the Talmud  Yerushalmi in which he says
> that Moshiach can come from  the dead, we can only conclude from this
> that this obscure modern commentator thought the idea was possible. We
> cannot deduce any more than that. This clarity in the relative  value
> of proofs is crucial in making a final evaluation of the  evidence.

> The texts that are generally brought revolve around  statements that
> either Daniel, King David, or Moshe will be  the future Moshiach.
> Since these righteous men are  deceased we can infer that there is
> nothing in Judaism that  contradicts the idea that Moshiach can come
> from the dead.  Since, as we proved in the previous chapter, Moshiach
> cannot come from the dead, the burden is on us to explain  these
> apparently explicit statements to the contrary. As we  shall see, this
> has already been done by those much greater  than we.

in chapter four he discusses the Rambam quoted by the OP:

> He initiated an unparalleled tshuvah movement that  brought many, many
> Jews back to observance. He fought the  spiritual battles of G-d
> against assimilation and secularism  by sending out mitzvah tanks and
> armies of youths. Thus,  these people conclude, he is at least
> bechezkas Moshiach.  Some will even claim that he accomplished 4 and
> 5. He built  a monumental holy place – 770 – in his place and helped  bring about the mass immigration of Russian Jews to Israel.  Thus,
> these people argue, the Rebbe is not only bechezkas  Moshiach, he is
> vadai Moshiach.
>
> Yet, there are problems with this theory. First of all, none of  these
> tasks are done. The Rebbe did not fully succeed in any  of these.
> There is still monumental ignorance and lack of  observance among Jews
> throughout the world and Israel is  still under siege by terrorists
> and Arab armies. The Temple  Mount remains under Arab control and the
> majority of Jews  still reside outside of Israel. The Rebbe's
> accomplishments  were glorious and awe-inspiring. However, they were
> not  sufficient to fit the Rambam's criteria for Moshiach. In fact,
> the Rebbe has not fulfilled any of the criteria for being  Moshiach
> except being a Torah scholar and religious man.  Let us look at the
> criteria again:
>
> 1. Compel all of Israel to walk in the way of Torah
> 2. Repair the breaches in observance
> 3. Fight the wars of G-d
>
> Furthermore, it is a basic rule of learning that the Rambam  was very
> precise with his language. **As many will argue  regarding the
> difference between “to die” and “to be killed”,  we must read each of
> the Rambam’s words with great care.**  The Rambam writes that in order
> to be bechezkas Moshiach  one must be a king from the house of David.
> Only by a wild  stretch of the imagination – and a careless reading of
> the  Rambam – can the Rebbe be considered to have been a king.
> Contrast this with Bar Kochba for whom there is  archaeological
> evidence that he ruled as a king and was  punctilious in his
> observance of mitzvos. The Rambam also  says that one who is bechezkas
> Moshiach will fight the wars  of G-d. In which battle did the Rebbe
> fight in the army? In  fact, the Rebbe wrote in Likkutei Sichos vol.
> 16 pp. 304-305  n. 49 that the Rambam’s language here of “fight the
> wars of  G-d” means literal wars including the destruction of Amalek.
>
> It is not merely a figure of speech. But the Rebbe did not  fight a war
> and did not destroy Amalek. The Rambam's definition of a failed
> Moshiach is quoted  above from halachah 5. Note that the Rambam says
> “did not  succeed… or was killed” so someone's not succeeding in
> completing the messianic task is sufficient to disqualify him  from
> being Moshiach. But how can the Rambam list not  accomplishing these
> five items as rendering someone  definitely not Moshiach? Maybe he
> will be resurrected and  finish these tasks? Or maybe he will complete
> them in his  trips to this world from under the Seat of Glory? No one
> can  ever fall into this category if the Moshiach can come back  from
> the dead and finish his messianic tasks. We must say  that, according
> to the Rambam, Moshiach cannot come back  from the dead to complete
> the criteria. Otherwise, half of this  halachah is impossible. We
> would never be able to declare  someone who is bechezkas Moshiach as
> being definitely not  the promised Moshiach for not succeeding. If we
> allow for  the possibility that someone can come back to this world
> and  finish these tasks, then we have nullified the Rambam's  words in
> this halacha. Rather, when someone who is  bechezkas Moshiach dies we
> unfortunately discover for  certain that he is not Moshiach.

See the first link above for more on this topic.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot +1 this as this proves why they are wrong, the OP was looking for an argument to prove them right.

Comment: @user6591 Actually I will +1 this, because he *does* bring the arguments used by the meshichistim.  In the same breath he quotes the counter-argument, but that's beside the point... :)

Comment: מן הלאו אתה שומע הן

Comment: "Wars of the Lord". Watch here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsADqkXyALk. At 1:30, the Rebbe uses the phrase to refer to real wars.

Answer (score 8):

Just for redundancy's sake, I'm included here a citation from [מדרש רבה on ויחי](http://www.tsel.org/torah/midrashraba/vayechi.html) that clearly shows that a messianic candidate is disqualified by death:

ויפול רוכבו אחור יחזרו דברים לאחוריהם לפי שהיה יעקב אבינו רואה אותו וסבור בו שהוא מלך המשיח כיון שראה אותו **שמת** אמר אף זה מת לישועתך קויתי ה

See Menachem Kasher's תורה שלימה for parallel midrashim.

Comment: Please translate

Comment: The words of the Midrash are: "Since Yaakov saw that he would die"- That's "die" and not "killed". Yaakov proclaimed לישועתך because he saw Shimshon "die"- how he died is irrelevant. (In any case, Shimshon wasn't killed- he committed suicide.)

Comment: מת is generic at best. It can mean הרג or not. It depends on the context of usage. In the context of the Midrash Rabbah, Yaacov Avinu is referring to what is described in Shoftim. Shimshon precipitated his own demise. That is more specifically called נהרג. Whether it is "suicide", as you say, is a whole other discussion. Suicide is prohibited. Shimshon prayed to HaShem to allow him this final battle with the Palestinians. HaShem granted his request. It doesn't suggest a violation of the prohibited act of suicide.

Answer (score 5):

See Bereishis Rabboh 98 where Yaakov Ovinu thought that Shimshon would be Moshiach.When he saw that he died, he said: "This one also died (i.e. and therefore can't be Moshiach)? Liyeshuoscho Kivisi HaShem"

Answer (score 2):

As one meshichister told a friend of mine, The Rambam explicitly says 'if he is killed'. Dying comfortably of old age or sickness doesn't fit the bill.

Disclaimer: the views posted are not the views of the poster.

Comment: Your answer makes me think that perhaps the 'next clause', the Rambam's reference to 'if he is killed', and 'proper and complete kings of the Davidic dynasty' is an allusion to those who fit the characteristics of a Moshiach ben Yosef, with strong elements of *ben David*. It could be referring specifically to the Lubavitcher Rebbe.

Comment: @user4651 That's because you are allowing yourself to be led by the view presented in your answer. The Rambam is discussing a Davidic descendent specifically. And this one that didn't get to be Moshiach is now on a long list of other Davidic non-Moshiachs.

Comment: Doesn't the OP already mention this pseudo-diyuk?

Comment: If we are allowing for resurrections to come finish the job, then why does killed vs died of old age matter? Can killed people not be resurrected?

Comment: I guess being knocked off is a divine sign of failure

Comment: @Mefaresh there is a somewhat parallel found in a Hakpada not to name after someone who was killed, as opposed to someone who died.

Comment: @Double maskim. I just figured I'd quote one who said this bipeh malei. Apparently they like this diyuk, not the diyuk com the seifa, and not logical arguments.

Comment: Actually Mefaresh, that is one of the points being made in Rambam's pasak about being killed. The original question related to how Moshiach ben Yosef was mentioned in the prophecy from Sefer Zerubbavel. It states that ben Yosef is murdered by Armilus. This same idea is repeated in Sefer Avkat Rochel and continued in Midrash Talpiot. There were views that said his murder didn't matter. The Vilna Gaon said in Kol HaTor that the decree of his being murdered had been removed and he would successfully complete his mission.

Comment: @Mefaresh, please see comment above.

Comment: @YaacovDeane so being killed doesn't disqualify?  Also am I the only one who doubts the authenticity of Kol Hatoras being ascribed to the Vilna Gaon?

Comment: @Mefaresh, whether using the explanation of Rav Kasher in the HaTekufah HaGadolah edition of Kol HaTor or the 1994 more complete edition, the Gra is reported to be of the view that Moshiach ben Yosef will not be murdered. There is speculation whether that meant at all, or until he completed his mission. The Rivlin sefer is not the only place to see the Gra's view of the redemption. There are plenty of sources and they all need to be looked at together. And as I mention elsewhere, this view in Rambam, is not held universally.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Does Rambam even believe in Mashiach ben Yosef?

Comment: @mevaqesh If he didn't, he would be placing on himself a judgement of being a 'kofer b'Torah' as he poskins in Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Teshuva, 3:14 & 3:17.

Comment: @YaacovDeane  he writes והכופרים בביאת הגואל the particular article indicates that there is only one Messiah. And he lists it separately from a kofer baTorah.|| In halakha 17 he writes that there are 3 categories of denial of the Torah. denial of the Written Law, Oral Law, and claim of abrogation. One can debate whether the Messiah is included in the Written or Oral laws, but that says nothing about Mashiach ben Yossef || I guess that Rav Saadya Gaon z"l is a kofer according to you.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Interestingly, you yourself claim over here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/messiah-ben-joseph-versus-messiah-ben-david#comment189394_4470 that Mashiach ben Yosef *is the same person** as Mashiach ben David according to Rambam. So essentially, besides for the Mashiach ben David that Rambam tells us about, there is not another mashiach...

Comment: @mevaqesh You should read my response there more carefully. It's not my statement. It's what the Lubavitcher Rebbe wrote himself. What's more, the many references listed both here and at other responses on this site should be learned. If you actually look, you will come to a different conclusion.

Comment: @mevaqesh בביאת הגואל is referring to the 'subject' of the 'coming of the redeemer'. It means someone who denies that this process occurs. It isn't addressing how many people are part of this process. Once again, try reading and learning the sources given.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I read your response with great care (deserved or not) and you are obviously endorsing the view you quote. || `What's more, the many references listed both here and at other responses on this site should be learned. If you actually look, you will come to a different conclusion` You just keep appealing to mysterious vindicating sources, and ignoring the substantial issues; like Rav Saadya Gaon. This is not a healthy dialogue.

Comment: @mevaqesh  What Saadia Gaon source? Emunot v'De'ot? He brings ben Yosef and ben David.

Comment: @Yaacov hey guys, wanna take this to chat already? Thanks.

Comment: No need for the diyuk of killed vs died. An “Unsuccessful Moshiach” only loses status of B’Chezkas Moshiach. The Rambam doesn’t classify this person as Moshiach Sheker. Rather as the Rambam states, “he is considered as all the other proper and complete kings of the Davidic dynasty who died.” He reverts back to his original status of “Raui Lehyos Moshiach” and can come from the living or the dead.

Comment: @DoubleAA you wrote: “If we are allowing for resurrections to come finish the job, then why does killed vs died of old age matter? Can killed people not be resurrected?” If you understand the Rambam as above it actually makes no difference.

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy That doesn't address why does killed lose the "status of B’Chezkas Moshiach" if he can just come back to life and finish later? And if you hold died is different, why doesn't died lose that?

Answer (score 1):

Many of those Chasidim who mistakenly believe the Rebbe obm is Moshiach do not believe that he died mamish. In fact, you will see printed articles, signs, etc. that refer to the fateful day of Gimmel Tammuz as the day "the Rebbe was nistar (concealed)", not niftar (deceased).

This belief is frequently circulated in Chabad magazines such as [Beis Moshiach](http://www.beismoshiachmagazine.org/articles/no-more-than-a-test.html), stating that R. Schneerson's "concealment" is a test and that he is:

> chai v’kayam b’gashmius (physically alive)

It is 'defended' by Roshei Yeshivos of Chabad yeshivahs such R. Wagner of Yeshiva Lubavitch of Johannesburg on video at length: [Does going to the ohel contradict believing that the Rebbe is physically alive?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmcZtso37C0)

It is even articulated in [songs](http://chabadcampsongs.blogspot.com/2008/08/official-songbook.html) circulated in some Chabad children's camps with the following stanza:

> Dear son you must understand / The Rebbe is only concealed / But the truth
> is that he is alive / And needs only to be revealed.

As mentioned in some of the answers here, these Chasidim go through many mental and philosophical hurdles to explain how and why the Rebbe "was nistar". None of them are traditional interpretations of the Jewish view of Moshiach. In fact, many of the "proofs" are similar to what has been brought by Christians, Sabbateans, and other heretics whose messianic figure died without having fulfilled the necessary requirements of Moshiach.

This is not meant to bring down those who believe this way, chas v'sholom. They are Jews who believe they are serving Hashem "b'chol levovcho uv'chol nafshecho". However they are misguided and we should daven that they receive clarity on the matter and do not stray from the way of Torah and mitzvos as it was performed by our ancestors.

[3](http://chabadcampsongs.blogspot.com/2008/08/official-songbook.html):

Comment: @Deuteronomy Shkoyach for the defense and the edits

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Hillel of Sklov, a student of the Gaon of Vilna, wrote Kol Hator based on the Gaon's teachings. This answer is based more on the title of the question than its content.

The Gaon considered King Cyrus, the two Hebrew midwives in Egypt, and others are considered to be on a divine mission, a mission of Moshiach ben Yosef.

I can't explain it very well, but what I heard is that the Moshiach ben Yosef fixes what's broken, and the Moshiach ben David polishes what is already whole.

The ben Yosef gets his, or her, hands dirty in fighting etc., and the ben David is more like Shlomo haMelekh, i. e. ruling without really fighting.

I think that different people have different amounts of the ben David or the ben Yosef quality. I also think its clear that the final Rebbe of the Lubavitch dynasty doesn't match the description given by the Rambam and the prophets of Israel for the Messianic era. Shabbetai Tzvi and J**** of Nazareth also didn't match these requirements, but the Lubavitcher Rebbe achieved more than either of those failed messiahs (obviously).

If the Hebrew calendar corresponds to 6 days of creation, the year 1990 C. E. corresponds to high noon on Erev Shabbat.

In Talmud Bavli Sanhedrin 97b, it is said that for two thousand years there was *tohu*, two thousand years the Torah flourished, and (footnote: Messiah will come) in the next two thousand years. So we can expect the Messianic era some time between 240 and 2240 C. E., well after the Bar Kochba revolt failed.

To quote Kol Hator,

8. [c] [Isa.  60:22] “in its time, I will hasten it.” Our Sages interpreted this principle to mean that, if they [the People of Israel] merit it, I will hasten it [the Redemption]; if not, I will bring it in its own time (Sanhedrin 98a).

I think there were opportunities that were missed.

Again in Kol Hator,

> The basic approach of the Gaon is encapsulated in the principle “Yosef
>   is still alive, ” meaning that the Mashiach ben Yosef is still alive
>   and will live, because, as it is written, every aspect of the
>   beginning of the Redemption is dependent on him.  Thus the decree
>   regarding his murder by Armilus the Wicked will be canceled.  It will
>   be canceled by extending the period of the exile, by afflictions that
>   the Mashiach ben Yosef will suffer and diseases he will bear, and also
>   by deeds that he will accomplish with great devotion, such as
>   gathering in exiles, which is his mission.  What will also help are
>   messianic pangs and afflictions connected with Eretz Israel, and our
>   regular, daily prayers for the life and success of Mashiach ben Yosef.
>   Those who occupy themselves with gathering in the exiles, lighten the
>   afflictions of Mashiach ben Yosef during the period called “the
>   footsteps of the Mashiach.” The decree regarding the death of Mashiach
>   ben Yosef will be nullified by subdivision into small parts, as in the
>   parable recounted in the Midrash.  There is a parable of a king who
>   became angry with his son and swore to throw a big stone at him. 
>   Afterwards, he regretted what he had said, and had compassion on him. 
>   In order to fulfill his vow nevertheless, he broke up the big stone
>   into many small ones and threw all these small stones at his son one
>   by one.  Thus the son was not killed, yet he suffered from the small
>   stones.  These are the pangs of the Mashiach: the suffering will come
>   gradually, together with the 999 footsteps of the Mashiach, in such a
>   way that the decree is divided into 999 small parts.

https://web.archive.org/web/20130528151557/http://www.yedidnefesh.com/kaballah/kol-hator/index.htm

I'm comfortable with believing that the Lubavitcher Rebbe was one of those 999 parts.

Apologies if this doesn't make sense, is off-topic, or is offensive.

Comment: It's a nice d'var torah, and nothing about it was offensive, but it kind of sidesteps the question.  The question is not whether the Rebbe Z"L was part of a *process* leading up to Moshiach; it's a question of whether he *was/is* the Moshiach, and how it's possible to reconcile that with the apparent disqualification for the job inherent in being dead.

Comment: I would say that my answer is/should be that the Rebbe was not **the** Moshiach ben David, but that the fact that he died puts him more in the ben Yosef category.

Comment: OK, as I said, it's a nice d'var Torah, but it is off topic.

Comment: And for those who like quoting the Vilna Gaon teaching as brought by Rabbi Hillel of Shklov, how do you incorporate it with what the Gaon teaches in regard to the concept of the Nachash HaKadmoni. The Gaon emphasizes that the Nachash starts from a single tail, splits into two bodies and then both heads return to bite the single tail and become one again. The Gaon explains in many places that this is what the concept of Moshiach ben Yosef and Moshiach ben David is about. Details can be found in his commentary to Tikkunei Zohar Chadash, Sifra d'Tzniutah and L'Shem Shevo v'Achlamah.

Comment: And this is in keeping with the Lubavitcher Rebbe's suggestion that Rambam's view is that in the final transition from exile to redemption, Moshiach ben Yosef and Moshiach ben David are one and the same person.

Comment: @user4651 moshiach ben yosef and moshiach ben dovid are the same person

Comment: @Dude How can someone be from two tribes at once?

Comment: The zohar says that moshe rabeinu will be the first and last redeemer yest we also know that moshiach must be ben dovid. Clearly all of these references to moshiach are dealing with his neshama

Comment: "The ben Yosef gets his, or her, hands dirty in fighting etc., " is there any indication aywhere that Moshiach can bea female? I'm pretty sure Rambam said that no woman can ever hold any position of leadership in Judaism

Comment: @user201 yes there is a source. The Gaon in this answer, specifically regarding Shifra and Push.

Comment: @DoubleAA can you quote that, I don't see anywhere where it says that any form of Moshiach wil be female, in fact that assertation seems to run contradictory to the entire Torah and everything we believe in: that women cannot have any kind of authority/kingship ever

Comment: @user201 "The Gaon considered King Cyrus, the two Hebrew midwives in Egypt, and others are considered to be on a divine mission, a mission of Moshiach ben Yosef." Maybe Mashiach ben Yosef isn't a position of authority/kingship. Maybe we don't all believe women cannot have any kind of authority/kingship ever. Either way that's what he says.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of a few ways. This is the general favorite of the Anti-Messianics (those who believe to themselves that the rebbe will be moshiach but who hate publicity on the matter):

The rambams psak in Laws of Kings 11:4 is stating moshiach has to be alive, but the next question is what the background learning for this psak is. It’s brought in achronim (yfei mareh and the Etz Yosef) that when shas and midrashim talk about “if he’s from the living...if he’s from the dead” it’s predicated on a doubt chazal had of when techiyas hameisim is. Thus “if he’s from the dead” means if the resurrection of the dead comes before moshiachs coming such that people are getting up anyways so one of them may become moshiach then it’s so and so. But if techiyas hameisim comes after the coming of moshiach and moshiach will need to be one of the living because nobody dead came back in time to become moshiach then it is so and so. Thus, since we rule that the world will continue as before during the days of moshiach and that the resurrection is later, moshiach must be from the living. This however, is if the redemption comes in its time (Beitah). But if we merit that moshiach should come with clouds of heaven, the lubavitcher rebbe explains that the resurrection will immediately occur and all the miracles of the future era will happen immediately. This being the case, the mechanism for a resurrected messiah is in place. To give one example, the son of the Ruzhiner said after his passing that his father will still be moshiach because the Ruzhiner had told him that the resurrection has been moved to the same day as the coming of moshiach. In fact, the reading of the Gemara in sanhedrin 98b according to whats brought in the sdei chemed is that if we merit then daniel will be moshiach from the dead. This all said, the Rambam isn’t even discussing a case of a divine miraculous redemption, but only of a natural one in its time without merit. This reading of the Rambam(that Laws of kings is only talking about a case of no merit but that a case of merit is not included) is brought by the Rebbe and is also agreed to by R Chaim Kanievsky in the book אחרית הימים in a footnote.

Summary: According to this way of learning, the rambams psak din cannot be used as a counter proof as the psak din is trying only to speak about a nonmeritorious redemption. in addition to this, the underlying reasoning for the psak din wouldnt apply. The door then seems wide open for its possibility so long as we merit and according to the Lubavitcher rebbe we have merited that a miraculous redemption take place.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that in order for the Rebbe to be Moshiach it is exactly *not* according to the quoted Rambam.

Comment: According to *this* interpretation of the rambams halachic reasoning(there are other formulations as well), the rambam by its nature is limited to speaking only about lo zachu beitah. However, in zachu achishena the psak is inapplicable. it is an overreach to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from here:

[Rambam Rejected Childless Messiah](https://shilohmusings.blogspot.com/2016/08/rambam-rejected-childless-messiah-by-mr.html)

Rambam, Hilchot Melachim, Chapter 4, paragraph 8:

> The King Messiah will take a one 13th part [7.69%] of all the lands
> that Israel conquers, for himself, and for his descendants forever.

Rambam, commentary on Mishnah Sanhedrin, chapter 10:

> When the Mashiach dies, his son will rule after him, and his grandson
> will rule after that.

Over the past 2,000 years, 36 Jewish men have claimed to be the messiah.
34 of them had no children, one of them had a daughter,
and one of them had two sons who died before he died.
None of them had a son and grandson to follow him.

When Rambam described the messiah as having a son and a grandson,
he achieved a super-concise refutation of all the false messiahs in the
1,000 years before him and all the false messiahs in the 1,000 years after him.

For more proof that the messiah will have sons, see the Metsudath David
commentary on Yechezkel chapter 44 verse 3 and Yechezkel chapter 45 verse 7,
which identifies the prince who leaves an inheritance to his sons as the King Messiah.

Comment: He doesn't state that as a requirement. And many disagree.

Comment: @shmosel Rambam states this as a FACT, not a requirement. It's disingenuous to cherry-pick which statements by the Rambam to bring as "proof" to the alleged messiahship of the rebbe, and to ignore the Rambam's statements that serve as a refutation of that same narrative.

Comment: This would be a great proof but it won't go far because they either believe he is still alive, or coming back :) BTW are you sure all of the 36 themselves claimed to be Moshiach or are some of them similar examples, where it is the followers who did this?

Comment: Treating the Mishneh Torah's qualifications as halachic requirement is not cherry-picking. The Rambam on Sanhedrin is merely describing the normal order of royal succession, same as it was in the past. That doesn't mean it's a binding rule. How could he be sure that every future king will have a male son to succeed him? Or will that be the one supernatural phenomenon in the times of moshiach?