# How is it possible to suggest that Moshiach must be alive when there is a clear Gemarah debating that

Tags: messiah, maseches-sanhedrin

I saw a conversation on Mi Yodeya, questioning if one who believes the Rebbe to be moshiach is a heretic.
The main basis of the argument was that Moshiach must be alive.
However, there is a clear Gemarah in Sanhedrin 98b:
"Rav said: if he is alive, he is like Rabeinu Hakodesh.
if he is amongst the dead, he is Daniel."
SO clearly moshiach can have passed away?
Anyone can explain the validity of such an argument?

Comment: I will not enter into writing an answer to this beyond what is already posted on this site so as not to cause unnecessary quarreling among Jews at this time. Rabbi Ahron Soloveitchik, zt”l, voluntarily signed a letter that summarized a talk he gave after the passing of the Lubavitcher Rebbe saying that belief that Moshiach can come from the dead to finish his mission is clearly within accepted & legitimate Orthodox Jewish belief and that no one should be condemned for such a belief. It was printed publicly and was later reaffirmed by the Rav. He was strongly criticized by his peers for this.

Comment: Related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59634/7303

Comment: Rashi seems to read it as "if it *would have been* of those who have since died." In other words, Daniel would have qualified in his time, but not necessarily would he still be eligible. According to his second interpretation, it's not listing actual candidates at all, just offering contemporary and historical examples of what Moshiach would be like.

Comment: @shmosel the rashi readys as follows אי מן חייא הוא כגון רבינו הקדוש: אם משיח מאותן שחיים עכשיו ודאי היינו רבינו הקדוש דסובל תחלואים וחסיד גמור הוה כדאמרינן בבבא מציעא (דף פה.) ואם היה מאותן שמתו כבר היה דניאל איש חמודות שנדון ביסורין בגוב אריות וחסיד גמור היה והאי כגון לאו דווקא ל"א כגון רבינו הקדוש כלומר אם יש דוגמתו בחיים היינו רבינו הקדוש ואם דוגמא הוא למתים היינו כגון דניאל איש חמודות:

Comment: so if you look he says if its from those who have already passed away.

Comment: Not sure what point you're responding to.